# My script doesnt work on host, but it works on localhost

Tags: javascript, host

I made small script, which uses PerformanceObserver in it

```
console.log(1);

const observer = new PerformanceObserver(list => {
    console.log(2);
    list.getEntries().forEach(entry => {
       if (entry.type === "back_forward") {
       const data = document.querySelector(".h1");
       data.textContent = "hello";
       setTimeout(function () {
           window.location.reload();
       }, 2000);
       }
    });
});

console.log(3)

observer.observe({ type: "navigation" });
```

*console logs are for test
When i launched it on localhost, everything worked perfectly, but when i deployed it on host - thats it. Nothing happens especially in chrome. There is no errors. There is no clue about it.

There is the site: https://cq25005.tw1.ru/

I tried a lot of ways to fix this problem, nothing helped

Comment: Everything that I need is to reload page when backwards browser button is clicked. May be there is other solution that will wok on host?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve but your code works as intended. When you go on another page, then use the "back" navigation button then your code executes and the `entry.type === "back_forward"` evaluates to `true`, and then properly defers the reload function.

Comment: @GuerricP what browser were you using? I and my friend visited this website on chrome latest version and this script didnt work

Comment: It works on Edge (Chromium) 108

Comment: @GuerricP can you try it exactly at chrome? i've tried it on another chromium browser and it worked, but in chorme - it didnt work